# What stops an attacker from breaking into your system without firewall?

Tags: 20.04, security, 22.04, ufw

My question is short but concise.

If you don't configure a firewall, can someone "just ssh" and brute force into your system if they know your ip address?

Comment: SSH server is not installed by default.

Comment: @Pilot6 what if it is installed? Or you have like a  http server running on localhost. Can someone just break in with a simple brute force?

Comment: If you have a service running available from outside that accepts passwords, then the answer is positive.

Comment: The question is incompletely specified. What's running on this system - which OS, which services, how are they configured for authentication? How is it connected to the internet? My system's IP is 192.168.1.2 - but this "someone"'s network could also have a system at 192.168.1.2 which could be a separate system. So what do you mean by "know your ip address"?

Comment: @muru I am new to cybersecurity in general a lot of things I dont understand yet. Like if you visit a website, they can see your IP address. I was thinking maybe you can just connect to it and try passwords.

Comment: I don't think this site is suited for giving you a course in cybersecurity. If I go to a website, they might see the IP of the whatever system was actually connected to the internet through which my network flowed - the router my ISP gave me, or maybe their gateway server, or maybe something else. There's no reason it should be the same as my "IP".

Comment: If you are new to cybersecurity, then most of your initial questions will be answered by a couple episodes of the the [Ubuntu Security Podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/). You will be able to ask much better questions after listening to a couple of those,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you are a desktop home user of Ubuntu. If you run any kind of Ubuntu server or cloud instance then this answer is not for you

## If you don't configure a firewall...

But you **enable** it then no one can ssh and brute force into your system.

Firewalls like ufw deny all incoming connections by default.

## If they know your IP address...

Assuming your computer is behind a home router, you have to configure your router's Network Address Translation (NAT) before anyone, including you can ssh into your home computer from outside.

So unless you open the front door in the form of NAT in your router no one can brute force your ssh server.

Hope this helps